# Underground Comix Story - 'Twilight of the Dogs'?

Tags: story-identification

I read this B&W story in an American underground comic sometime in the 1970s. I am almost certain it was named 'Twilight of the Dogs'. The GCD lists two Richard Corben stories by this title: one in Fantagor #1 (10 pages) and a reprint in Gasm #4 (only 4 pages). What little I can remember of the story: aliens have taken over the Earth and human civilization is gone. Two men wander like starving animals across the land, cursing the aliens (who are never seen) as they travel by high-speed train from one sealed city to another. I can't remember what happened to the first guy, but the second one manages to get hit by one of the trains and dies. Is this the story I'm looking for?